# Why this select tag not work right in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-hooks, use-state

Code :

```
const Home = () => {
const location = useLocation();

const [lang, setLang] = useState((location.state === undefined)?"KorService":location.state.lang);


const tmp = (lang === "KorService")
    ? [//Kor Ver]
    : [//Eng Ver];

 ...

const selectLang = (e) => {
    setLang(e.target.value)
}
 ...

return (
    <div>
        <div className="header">
            <h1>{tmp[0]}</h1>
            <React.Fragment>
                <button className="lang" onClick={openModal}>Aa</button>
                <Modal open={modalOpen} close={closeModal} header={tmp[1]}>
                    <select className="langoption" onChange={selectLang}>
                        <option value="KorService">한국어</option>
                        <option value="EngService">English</option>
                    </select>
                </Modal>
            </React.Fragment>
        </div>
       ...
);
```

};

Result :

- Opened Modal and clicked English option : **Worked Well**
- When selecting the English option and selecting the Korea option with the modal window open : **Worked Well**
- When lang is English, open modal clicked Korea : **Not Worked**

Want :

- When user clicked any option, it operate immediately. I want to resolve this problem to selected Korea option well

Comment: Can you share a playground link?

Comment: That.. sounds very strange behaviour. Does your URL already update when you change the language? Because I suspect the issue is with the `useLocation` and default value for state

Comment: I don't have playground link, instead github. link is here [link]https://github.com/riverDeltaProject/Frontend/blob/main/src/component/presentation/Home.js

Comment: @C12H22O12 I saw in your repo that you have i18next/react-i18next in your packages, so why use useLocation? ... check my example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g7poop?file=src%2Flayout%2FSwitchLang.js

Comment: @C12H22O12 See i18next-browser-languagedetector package

Comment: The value should be reflected on the other page, so I wrote useLocation. I saw the page using your i18n. It was exactly the function I wanted. When I used the i18n, I automatically detected the language of the page and couldn't use it more, but I think I should try again.